# looks is or looks are

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> 1. Their pale and colourless  looks are not liked by slender girls.
> 2. Their pale and colourless looks is not liked by slender girls.

I cannot choose which verb [is or are] is suitable for above sentence. From my point of view, I choose *are* as I think "looks" is a plural noun.

Comment: The term is, indeed, a plural noun: *looks*. So it would be "looks *are*" ...

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence should read

> Their pale and colourless ***look*** is not liked by slender girls.

you want to use "look" since it is the "type of look" or appearance of *somebody* that is being described.  "Pale and colourless" is a compound adjective, similar to "bacon and eggs" and so is singular.

> [**look**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/look) - noun
> 17.
> the way in which a person or thing appears to the eye or to the mind; aspect:

It is also singular because even though a group is being talked about, they all have the same singular "look"

> The military always have a unified **look** about them.

![here][1]
[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3MoS.jpg

![here][2]
[2]:https://image.shutterstock.com/shutterstock/photos/91932101/display_1500/stock-photo-london-may-british-royal-guards-perform-the-changing-of-the-guard-in-buckingham-palace-on-may-91932101.jpg

One notes the diversity in height of Her Majesty's Royal Guard.

[Heroin Chic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroin_chic) was a **look** popularized in the 1990's by Kate Moss, amoung others, with its gaunt look, smokey eyes, and pale skin

![here][3]
[3]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL3rN.jpg

Although they have individual and different **looks**

[![here][4]][4]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](https://scstylecaster.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/jumbo-481.jpg?w=712&h=400&crop=1))</sub>
[4]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuFs2.jpg


Together, they have the Coachella **look**

[![here][5]][5]
<sub>(source: [ytimg.com](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uuAFybbqFTY/maxresdefault.jpg))</sub>
[5]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA9RM.jpg

Comment: Peter, could you please elaborate?  You are on the right track, but "pale and colorless" is (to some extent) irrelevant since *looks* actually agrees with *their*.  Why would it be more correct to say "their **look**" and not "their **looks**"?

Comment: @Andrew, I've editted my answer to add some more examples with a nod to Herion Chic.

Comment: Yes, again you're on the right track, but I think it's common is to use *looks* when talking about (facial) *features*, and *look* when talking about *style*.  For example, ["Do looks mean everything?"](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090101200152AAbYVN6).  So there's a question whether we're talking about their *natural* appearance, or an *affected* fashion trend.

Comment: **Look** is not necessarily only about style "You should have seen the **look** in his eyes when I told him!", "I don't like the **look** of that!", "The **look** of love" in these cases "looks" would not be correct.  However, "His **look** can be very formal at times" can describe what fashion he is wearing, whereas "The girls are attracted by his good **looks** and charm" can describe his general appearance.

Comment: "*Their pale and colourless* **look are** *not liked by slender girls.*" Slender girls (plural) `do not like the pale and sallow look`. I think there is a case for using the plural verb here. Maybe both verb forms could be used. I agree that **look** must be singular in the OP?s example.

Comment: @Mari-LouA it's actually a cool example of English quirkiness.  How confusing to have both "look" and "looks" be correct with both plural and singular nouns, depending on what you want to say.